# HOWTO extract specific text from HTML/XML ,using cURL and HTTP

Tags: http, dom, xpath, curl

I successfully downloaded a file from a remote server using cURL and HTTP, but the file includes all the HTML code.

Is there a function in cURL so that I can extract the values I want?

For example, I am getting:

```
    ...
    <body>
    Hello,Manu
    </body>
    ...
```

But I only want `Hello,Manu`.

Thanks in advance,

Manu

Comment: Are you using curl at the command line or as a library in another language

Answer (score 0):

try using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or any other XML parser.

```
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_content); // result from curl
$xpath= new DOMXPath($doc);
echo $xpath->query('//body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

alternatively for command line you can use

```
curl 'http://.................' | xpath '//body'
```